# Electron-builder make simple executable instead of installer

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I made an Electron app, but it is unnecessarily trying to install itself on some platforms. My app is very simple enough that it makes more sense to be a non-installing executable. Is there an option for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set target to `portable` . This will directly run your executable without any installer.

You can find more information here: https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis#portable